# Java 11 SSL exception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-11, java-security

During an attempt to upgrade one of my applications from java 8 to java 11, I run into a weird SSL exception about "unable to find valid certification"

the provisioning of this application overwrites default jdk / jre `cacerts` with `cacerts` from `ca-certificates-java` package so before and after the upgrade, the certificates in the key store should be the same (this is also verified using `keytools`):

```
# java 8
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Sep 11 22:52 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/pki/java/cacerts

# java 11
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct 29 21:22 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/pki/java/cacerts
```

Investigated a few days but I didn't get myself anywhere. I think this may have been caused by changes in `SunJSSE` security `Provider` between version `1.8` and `11.0` but I cannot confirm.

I'm not familiar with java security and would like to reach out for help. The example has been simplified to this [project](https://github.com/duxing/netty-ssl) and the instructions on reproducing this issue is in the [README.md](https://github.com/duxing/netty-ssl/blob/master/README.md)

Exception call stack:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:641)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1048)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:995)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1502)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1516)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1400)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:619)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 38 more
```

Note:
the project was set up with `netty` and the ssl context was set up using `netty`'s `SslContext`. I've tried using `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` too:

```
SSLEngine engine = SSLContext.getDefault().createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(true);
```

And this results in the same exception and call stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran your docker image with Java debugging (`-Djavax.net.debug=all`) and found the following.  This [Github Issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/9544) may help you find a solution.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0F|nioEventLoopGroup-2-1|2019-11-06 06:13:01.316 UTC|CertificateMessage.java:357|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 90 76 89 18 E9 33 93 A0",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=invalid2.invalid, OU="No SNI provided; please fix your client."",
    "not before"         : "2015-01-01 24:00:00.000 UTC",
    "not  after"         : "2030-01-01 24:00:00.000 UTC",
    "subject"            : "CN=invalid2.invalid, OU="No SNI provided; please fix your client."",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
```

Comment: I can confirm this. Changing your code in `HttpClientInitializer.java` to add host and port `ctxBuilder.build().newHandler(alloc, uri.getHost(), port);` fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while we migrated to JAVA11 from JAVA8, if I remember, as a workaround copying the contents of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-9.b11.fc28.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts` to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` solved the problem.

Comment: Copying the files from an old version to the new should not be the solution. This is dirty.

Comment: I've setup certificates under jdk/jre to be a symlink to certificates from `ca-certificates` package.
```
# java 8
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Sep 11 22:52 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/pki/java/cacerts

# java 11
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct 29 21:22 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/pki/java/cacerts
```
so both java 8 and java 11 should be using the same set of certificates at runtime