# How to resolve PKIX path building failed in aws lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, pkix

I was working on creating AWS Lambda which will consume the data from private queue(in client server).It need some trusted certificate to be added. In local, I have executed the following command:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "clientcert" -file "..\client.cer" -keystore cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

it was working fine.
Now I have uploaded my lambda function in aws console, am getting same error as follows:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to add trusted certificate to aws lambda in console

Comment: I have seen this or similar message when it was not possible to validate that the certificate is not revoked neither via OCSP nor via CLR. Alas, I have not seen it in context of AWS but when we were trying to set up HTTPS on Jetty.

Comment: It actually looks like one issue that I have seen before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705427/java-11-ssl-exception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targ#comment103741272_58724300

Answer (score 1):

You have too create truststore programitically See below code for reference

```
        // Declare path of trust store and create file
        String trustStorePath = "/tmp/trust";
        // try creating above directory and path if you get error no such file 

        // Create Truststore using Key store api
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        // locate the default truststore
        String filename = System.getProperty("java.home")
                + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {

            keyStore.load(fis, "changeit".toCharArray());
        }

        // Add Certificate to Key store
        CertificateFactory certF = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate cert = certF.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("your certificate path"));
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("any alias", cert);

        // Write Key Store
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(trustStoreFile)) {
            keyStore.store(out, "changeit".toCharArray());
        }

        // Set Certificates to System properties
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

This you can test locally as well on  aws lambda.
Hope this will solve the issue

Comment: * You can keep your certificate in s3 or keep it in resources of lambda directory

Comment: My application having same kind of code is hosted on AWS. while renewing expired cert, 
QA environment works fine, but for PROD, it's giving error as below.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Any idea what could be the issue?